# python BeautifulSoup.How do I get the first text under multiple identical tags

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

How do I get the first text under multiple identical tags
I used BeautifulSoup to get some labels that are the same, and I just want to get "text05".

```
<p class="m-t-xs">test01
    <a class="a-blue" href="http://****">test02</a>
    <span class="m-l">test03</span>
    <span class="m-l">test04</span>
</p>
<p class="m-t-xs">test05
    <span class="m-l">test06</span>
</p>
<p class="m-t-xs">test07</p>
```

As you can see, their class is the same.And how can i use BeautifulSoup to get what i want.

Answer (score 0):

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'html.parser')
tags = soup.findAll('p', {'class': 'm-t-xs'})
```

`tags` will then be a list of the `p` tags. Select your data from the appropriate tag:

```
tags[1].find(text = True).strip() # 'test05'
```